# PIG Group by avoid Bag

Tags: apache-pig

This is a basic PIG question.
I have my data something like this

```
10  | Dog
15 | Cow
20 | Dog
15 | Elephant
15 | Dog
25 | Elephant
```

I want to find the average weight of each animal and have the output as this :

```
Dog | 12.5
Elephant | 20
Cow | 15
```

I am able to use GROUP by and get the result, but the result is a bag, something like this :

```
 {(Dog), (Dog) } | 12.5
 {(Elephant), (Elephant)} | 20
 {(Cow)} | 15
```

How can I extract just the individual animal ?

I am using GROUP by like this.

```
--animal_weight is derived through other means
animal_by = GROUP animal_weight by (animal);
results = FOREACH animal_by GENERATE animal_weight.animal as animal_name, AVG(animal_weight.weight) as kg;
STORE results INTO '$output_4' USING PigStorage('|');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group` instead of `animal_weight.animal`.Note that from your sample data,Dog should have an average of weight (10+20+15)/3 = 15 kg

```
results = FOREACH animal_by GENERATE group as animal_name, AVG(animal_weight.weight) as kg;
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thanks ! I just came up with 12.5, should have done the math :-)